# CakePHP 2 - Two foreign keys of a table linked to the same single table primary key

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.9

How can i use cakephp 2X model hasone or other association concept here to execute the find query.

[image: My two tables]

In my Schinfo.php model is

```php
class Schinfo extends AppModel {
    public $tablePrefix = 'sko_';
    public $hasOne = [
        'State' => [
            'className' => 'Masterlocation',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_locid'
        ],
        'City' => [
            'className' => 'Masterlocation',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_locid'
        ],
        'Area' => [
            'className' => 'Masterlocation',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_locid'
        ]
    ];
}
```

With the above I got

```sql
SELECT
    `Schinfo`.`skool_id`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_code`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_name`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_addr`,
    `Schinfo`.`master_state_id`,
    `Schinfo`.`master_city_id`,
    `Schinfo`.`master_area_id`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_pin`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_board`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_type_id`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_affilated_to`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_affilated_no`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_contact_no`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_mailid`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_website`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_logo`,
    `Schinfo`.`skool_delete`,
    `State`.`master_locid`,
    `State`.`master_parentid`,
    `State`.`master_locname`,
    `State`.`is_checked`,
    `City`.`master_locid`,
    `City`.`master_parentid`,
    `City`.`master_locname`,
    `City`.`is_checked`,
    `Area`.`master_locid`,
    `Area`.`master_parentid`,
    `Area`.`master_locname`,
    `Area`.`is_checked` 
FROM
    `skoolata`.`sko_schinfos` AS `Schinfo` 
    LEFT JOIN
        `skoolata`.`sko_masterlocations` AS `State` 
        ON (`State`.`master_locid` = `Schinfo`.`id`) 
    LEFT JOIN
        `skoolata`.`sko_masterlocations` AS `City` 
        ON (`City`.`master_locid` = `Schinfo`.`id`) 
    LEFT JOIN
        `skoolata`.`sko_masterlocations` AS `Area` 
        ON (`Area`.`master_locid` = `Schinfo`.`id`) 
WHERE
    1 = 1
```

Now I need to change

```sql
LEFT JOIN
    skoolata.sko_masterlocations AS State
    ON (State.master_locid = Schinfo.id) 
LEFT JOIN
    skoolata.sko_masterlocations AS City 
    ON (City.master_locid = Schinfo.id) 
LEFT JOIN
    skoolata.sko_masterlocations AS Area 
    ON (Area.master_locid = Schinfo.id)
```

to

```sql
LEFT JOIN
    skoolata.sko_masterlocations AS State
    ON (State.master_locid = Schinfo.master_state_id) 
LEFT JOIN
    skoolata.sko_masterlocations AS City 
    ON (City.master_locid = Schinfo.master_city_id) 
LEFT JOIN
    skoolata.sko_masterlocations AS Area 
    ON (Area.master_locid = Schinfo.master_area_id)
```

to get my desire output

Answer (score 0):

You want to define three relationships, `Country`, `State` and `City` and specify the `className` for each to be the model you are linking to, for example `Location`. You can then also specify the column you will be using as the foreign keys in your `Student` model using `foreignKey`:-

```
public $hasOne = [
    'Country' => [
        'className' => 'Location',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id'
    ],
    'State' => [
        'className' => 'Location',
        'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
    ],
    'City' => [
        'className' => 'Location',
        'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
    ]
];
```

Then when it comes to finding the results you can use `contain` like:-

```
$students = $this->Student->find('all', [
    'contain' => ['Country', 'State', 'City']
]);
```

Comment: tnxs for your quick response. Please chk my question as I updated this. I attached my table relation view. masterLocation -> loc_id is linked to 3 column of schoolInfo table

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using CakePHP naming conventions for your table columns? It makes things more hard work.

Comment: I m no using any naming conventions till now, but with your code its help me to resolve my query upto 80%. but still their is a problem. I m updatting my table structure & model code snipet. plz chk and let me know, what i need to do more.